# how can i see how many items are selected in a pivotable slicer via vba

Tags: excel, vba, count, pivot-table, slicers

I have a a pivot table with slicers on microsoft excell, and i want to make a macro where something happens if more than one item is selected on the slicer.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I wrote to grab the selections made in a slicer. It will return a comma separated string of selected slicer items.

You can adapt this to just return a number of selected items if you like. Although personally I think it's more important knowing which items are selected.

```
'This function takes one parameter
'This is the Formula name for the slicer
'you can find this name by right clicking on a slicer
'and choosing Slicer Settings...
Public Function getSlicerChoices(SlicerName As String) As String
    Dim slicerval       As SlicerCache
    Dim sItm            As SlicerItem

    Set slicerval = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName)

    For Each sItm In slicerval.VisibleSlicerItems
        If sItm.Selected Then
            If sItm.Name <> "(blank)" Then
                If getSlicerChoices = "" Then
                    getSlicerChoices = "'" & Replace(Trim(sItm.Name), "'", "''") & "'"
                Else
                    getSlicerChoices = "'" & Replace(Trim(sItm.Name), "'", "''") & "'," & getSlicerChoices
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sItm

    'Take last comma off the string
    If Right(getSlicerChoices, 1) = "," Then
        getSlicerChoices = Left(getSlicerChoices, Len(getSlicerChoices) - 1)
    End If

    getSlicerChoices = Replace(getSlicerChoices, "(blank)", "")
    Set slicerval = Nothing

End Function
```